# Cannot get Azure ML Model Management API to work in GermanyWestCentral as in EastUs for example

Tags: azure, api, azure-machine-learning-service

Considering the Azure ML API and how to manage models with it, I've got the following problem.

## Here is the sequence that works:

1. Obtain a token(OK) - > POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantId}}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantId%7D%7D/oauth2/token)
2. List Workspaces (OK) -> GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces?api-version=2018-03-01-preview](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7B%7BSubscriptionId%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces?api-version=2018-03-01-preview)
   I've got several workspaces, some created in EastUS and some in GermanWestCentral regions
3. In the json returned from previous API call, there is an attribute returned for each workspace called discoveryUrl which is either 'https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/discovery' or 'https://eastus.api.azureml.ms/discovery'
4. Invoking GET https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/discovery returns

```
{
    "api": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "catalog": "https://catalog.cortanaanalytics.com",
    "experimentation": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "gallery": "https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/project",
    "history": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "hyperdrive": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "labeling": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "modelmanagement": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms",
    "pipelines": "https://germanywestcentral.aether.ms",
    "studio": "https://ml.azure.com"
}
```

5. Invoking GET https://eastus.api.azureml.ms/discovery returns

```
{
    "api": "https://eastus.api.azureml.ms",
    "catalog": "https://catalog.cortanaanalytics.com",
    "experimentation": "https://eastus.experiments.azureml.net",
    "gallery": "https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/project",
    "history": "https://eastus.experiments.azureml.net",
    "hyperdrive": "https://eastus.experiments.azureml.net",
    "labeling": "https://eastus.experiments.azureml.net",
    "modelmanagement": "https://eastus.modelmanagement.azureml.net",
    "pipelines": "https://eastus.aether.ms",
    "studio": "https://ml.azure.com"
}
```

6. The modelmanagement url do not have the same structure in both regions

- "modelmanagement": "https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms"
- versus "modelmanagement": "https://eastus.modelmanagement.azureml.net",

(well fine, that should not be an issue)

7. Now invoking GET [https://eastus.modelmanagement.azureml.net/api/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{{workspaceName}}/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100](https://eastus.modelmanagement.azureml.net/api/subscriptions/%7B%7BSubscriptionId%7D%7D/resourceGroups/%7B%7BresourceGroupName%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/%7B%7BworkspaceName%7D%7D/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100)
   do return data describing the services available under the workspace

## But the problem is that invoking:

GET [https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/api/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{{workspaceName}}/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100](https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/api/subscriptions/%7B%7BSubscriptionId%7D%7D/resourceGroups/%7B%7BresourceGroupName%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/%7B%7BworkspaceName%7D%7D/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100) returns a 530 ERROR with "unknown to the cluster" in the body of the response

Any idea or hints on why this and how to get around this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 530 is kind of authentication error as far as I know. Please check the input var your used for below bugged URL

[https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/api/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{{workspaceName}}/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100](https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms/api/subscriptions/%7B%7BSubscriptionId%7D%7D/resourceGroups/%7B%7BresourceGroupName%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/%7B%7BworkspaceName%7D%7D/services?api-version=2018-03-01-preview&count=100)

Comment: Yep, but as stated above, for sure the token used, works fine to invoke other API in both region germanywestcentral & eastus....